# Java + SQL Server: Resultset is null?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, resultset

I am new to using java with a database and I have been trying following code:

```
public int getDateDiff(int OrderID) {
    Connection conn = DBConnection.getConnection();
    Integer diff = null;
    String getdiffSQL = "SELECT DATEDIFF( DAY , StartDate , EndDate ) FROM CarOrder WHERE OrderID = ?;";
    try {
        PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(getdiffSQL); 
        pstm.setInt(1, OrderID);
        ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery(getdiffSQL);
            while (rs.next()) {
                diff = rs.getInt(1);
            }
        }
     catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return diff;
}
```

I tried running this but i encounter this

> "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException"

and the the return diff is null. Please tell me what wrong in this and how do i fix this.

Comment: When using a `PreparedStatement` call `executeQuery()`, not  `executeQuery(String query)` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`PreparedStatement#executeQuery()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery()) does not take a parameter and you should not be passing the query string.  Instead use this pattern:

```
PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(getdiffSQL); 
pstm.setInt(1, OrderID);
ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery();   // no parameter
```

This is a fairly common mistake made when using JDBC, partly because [`Statement#executeQuery()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)) *does* take the query string as a parameter.  Add to this tutorials like [MkYong](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/) which make the same mistake as the OP and it is easy to see why this error is so prevalant.

Comment: Correct implementations of JDBC 4.0 (or higher) should always throw an exception if `executeQuery(String)` (and its siblings) is called on a `PreparedStatement` or `CallableStatement`.